# How to find a closed form formula for the following recurrence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I have to find a closed form formula for the following recurrence relation which describes Strassen's matrix multiplication algorithm -

$$T(n) = 7\,T\left(n \over 2\right) + \frac{18}{16}n^2$$ with the base case $T(1) = 1$ and $n = 2^j$, I have been able to reduce the formula to the following form:

$$T(2^j) = 7^j + \frac{3}{2}\,4^{j} \left[\left(\frac74\right)^j - 1\right],$$ the last step in this formula is plugging in $n = 2^j$ to get an expression in $n$ but somehow I can't reduce it further, can someone tell how to do this to get an expression in $n$?

Comment: Try using $j=\log_2 n$ and $a^{log_2 n}=2^{\log_2 a \log_2 n}=n^{\log_2 a}$.

Comment: done got it thanks a lot :)

Comment: Add your own answer then.

Comment: $(5/2)*n^(lg7) - (3/2)*n^2$

Comment: I meant as a true answer, not as a comment.

Comment: sure will add it in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

We can compute **exact** formulas for your recurrence and not just at powers of two. Suppose we first solve the recurrence
$$S(n) = 7 S(\lfloor n/2\rfloor) + \frac{18}{16} n^2$$
with $S(0)=0.$ (This will produce $S(1) = \frac{18}{16}$ instead of one, which we'll correct later.)

Then let $$n= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} d_k 2^k$$ be the binary representation of $n$ and unroll the recursion to get the following **exact** formula for $S(n):$
$$S(n) = \frac{18}{16} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} 7^j
\left(\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} d_k 2^{k-j} \right)^2
= \frac{18}{16} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^j
\left(\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} d_k 2^k \right)^2.$$
To get an upper bound on this consider a string of one digits, which gives
$$S(n)\le \frac{18}{16} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^j
\left(\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} 2^k \right)^2
= \frac{18}{16} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^j
\left(2^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor+1}- 2^j\right)^2
\\ =  \frac{18}{16} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} 
\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor-j}
\left(2^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor+1}- 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor-j}\right)^2
\\ =  \frac{18}{16} 
\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}2^{2\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}
\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} 
\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{-j} (2-2^{-j})^2
\\=\frac{18}{16} 
7^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}
\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} 
\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{-j} (2-2^{-j})^2.$$
Now the sum term converges to a constant and we have for the upper bound the asymptotics
$$\frac{18}{16} \times 7^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} \times \frac{49}{10}
= \frac{441}{80} \times 7^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}.$$

For a lower bound consider a one digit followed by a string of zeros, which gives
$$S(n)\ge \frac{18}{16} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^j
2^{2\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}
= \frac{18}{16} 2^{2\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}
\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} 
\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor-j}
\\ = \frac{18}{16} 2^{2\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}
 \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}
\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{-j}
= \frac{18}{16} 7^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} 
\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{-j}.$$
The sum term once more converges to a constant and we get for the lower bound complexity the asymptotics $$\frac{18}{16}\times 7^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} \times\frac{7}{3}
= \frac{21}{8} \times 7^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}.$$

Putting the two bounds together we get a complexity of
$$S(n) \in \Theta(7^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}) =
\Theta(2^{\log_2 7\times \lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}) = \Theta(n^{\log_2 7}).$$

This being Strassen the point was to show that the complexity is better than $\Theta(n^3),$ the naive matrix multiplication, which it is, because $\log_2 7 < 3$.

To conclude this calculation we return to $T(n)$ which was supposed to have $T(1)=1$ and not $18/16.$ We can compensate for this by putting
$$T(n) = -\frac{2}{16} 7^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} + S(n).$$
This term only changes the coefficient on the two bounds and does not affect the order of growth.

There are more Master Theorem type calculations at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595904/can-master-theorem-be-applied-on-any-of-these).

**Addendum.** Interestingly if we compute the partial sums for the lower bound we obtain
$$-\frac{2}{16} 7^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} +\frac{18}{16} 7^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} 
\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{-j}
= -\frac{2}{16} 7^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} + 
\frac{18}{16} 7^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} 
\frac{1-4/7\times(4/7)^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}}{1-4/7}
\\= -\frac{2}{16} 7^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} + 
\frac{18}{16} 7^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} \times \frac{7}{3}
- \frac{18}{16} \times \frac{4}{3} \times 4^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}
\\ =  +\frac{5}{2}  7^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor} 
- \frac{3}{2} \times 4^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor},$$
which matches up perfectly with the formula that was proposed as an answer in the original question.